# How to restore previous changes in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8

I am trying to restore previous changes.Example If i selected checkboxes and dropdown values in tab one then i click tab two and selected some dropdown values then i click tab one.Now i want to see my previous changes in checkbox and dropdown.How we can do it? Is it possible in angular 8.

app.component.html:

```
<my-tabs (selectedTabClick)="test($event,'tab_one')">
  <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'"  id="tab_one" #tab_one>
  <div *ngIf="tabflag.tab_one">
    <table>....</table>
  </div>
  </my-tab>
  <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2" id="tab_two" #tab_two>
  <div *ngIf="tabflag.tab_two">
  <table>....</table>
  </div>

  </my-tab>
</my-tabs>
```

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-example-6a8jmb?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do with `[hidden]` attribute if you use `*ngIf` it will run on condition and if condition is not satisfy then it will remove from DOM so you need do it with some code:

1. put `[hidden]="tabflag.tab_one"` instead of `*ngIf="tabflag.tab_one"`
2. put `[hidden]="tabflag.tab_two"` instead of `*ngIf="tabflag.tab_two"`
3. put `tabflag={ tab_one:true, tab_two:false }`

and last put method `test(event)` method into **ts**

```
test(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.tab.id == 'tab_one') {
      this.tabflag.tab_one = false;
      this.tabflag.tab_two = true;
    } 

    if(event.tab.id == 'tab_two'){
      this.tabflag.tab_two = false;
      this.tabflag.tab_one = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Table data will be more like 100 rows so I have used ngIf for lazy loading purpose.So How can i use hidden?

Comment: what are doing with lazy loading and if you using `*ngIf` then it will refresh with based on condition so you can't do with `*ngIf`

Comment: you are using normal table use primeng table it will give use attribute just you need to put into inside table tag check [here](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)

Comment: Yes..I will use primeng table.Can you use primeng table inside tabs?

Comment: Yes.I can use But i am asking rxjs state management for restore? How to implement rxjs state management?